# How to grep necessary info from multi-line data using regex?

Tags: python, parsing, text, multiline

```
||/ software                                   version                                          some_text    Description
+++-======================================-===================================================-============-===============================================================================
AA  SOFTWARE1                                   1.1.1.1-UBUNTU                                  GHGFHGFH     Description1
AA  SOFTWARE2                                   1.1.1.2-UBUNTU_HGSFHF                           JGJHGKGK     Description2
BB  SOFTWARE3                                   1.2.3.4.5                                       JHGJHGJG     Description3
```

Above is a sample text format stored in a string. This could have asa many as 1000 of lines. Out of these, need to extract software and corresponding version details.

Approach1 : split based on new line and split each line based on space and capture the second and third item in a list (Not a great approach)

Approach2: Using regex to compile and store them.

I believe second approach is good.

```
regex = r".*(AA|BB)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)"
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
```

How can I grep those software and version details from each line and store them in dictionary or any other format ?

Comment: If the format of the lines is consistent splitting and grabbing the fields is the best option. Why do you think regex would be better?

Comment: Using `.*` Matches the whole line. If the software and version do not contain spaces, you can use 3 capture groups `^(AA|BB)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)` https://regex101.com/r/uEZ2du/1

Comment: @alec_djinn to avoid multiple splitting and using additional lists and all. A dictionary key value would be very easy to access and efficient regex.

Comment: @Thefourthbird software name can be of even more chars and so the number of spaces between software name and version are different. regex would be best option.

Comment: Then perhaps you can leverage the difference in number of whitespace chars `^(AA|BB)\s{2,}(\S.*?)\s{2,}(\S+)` https://regex101.com/r/L5VfSM/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird how do you assign them to dictionary ? which could have huge number of such items form multiple number of lines ?

Comment: @Learner What do you want to assign to a dictionary? What  should be the key, and what should be the value?

Comment: @Thefourthbird key would be software name, as it would be unique and value would be it's version. You can post it as aswer below, so that I can upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want 2 capture groups with the value of software(that can contain spaces) in group 1, and version in group 2, you can use the difference in number of whitespace chars between the values (Assuming the software does not contain more whitespace chars than between the fields)

```
^(?:AA|BB)\s{2,}(\S.*?)\s{2,}(\S+)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:AA|BB)` Match either `AA` or `BB` in a non capture group
- `\s{2,}` Match 2 or more whitespace chars
- `(\S.*?)` **Group 1** capture a single non whitspace char followed by any char as least as possible
- `\s{2,}` Match 2 or more whitespace chars
- `(\S+)` **group 2**, capture 1+ non whitespace chars

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SyvrcS/1).

If you want to create a dictionary with group 1 as the key and group 2 as the value:

```
import re

pattern = r"^(?:AA|BB)\s{2,}(\S.*?)\s{2,}(\S+)"

s = ("||/ software                                   version                                          some_text    Description\n"
            "+++-======================================-===================================================-============-===============================================================================\n"
            "AA  SOFTWARE1 this is some text                                   1.1.1.1-UBUNTU                                  GHGFHGFH     Description1\n"
            "AA  SOFTWARE2                                   1.1.1.2-UBUNTU_HGSFHF                           JGJHGKGK     Description2\n"
            "BB  SOFTWARE3                                   1.2.3.4.5                                       JHGJHGJG     Description3")


dct = dict(re.findall(pattern, s, re.M))
print(dct)
```

Output

```
{'SOFTWARE1 this is some text': '1.1.1.1-UBUNTU', 'SOFTWARE2': '1.1.1.2-UBUNTU_HGSFHF', 'SOFTWARE3': '1.2.3.4.5'}
```

---

You might also make the pattern a bit more specific, matching the example data for the version column:

```
^(?:AA|BB)\s{2,}(\S.*?)\s{2,}(\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?:-\w+)?)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hAPVyH/1)

Comment: Thank you @The fourth bird.

Comment: dct = dict(re.findall(pattern, s, re.M)) , was not aware of this. This is good one. But if i want to scale it further. Say, a dictionary contains software name as key and it's value goes like {version: "", description: "", "some_text":""} (considering all the above 4 columns), how can we achieve this ?

Comment: @Learner You can assemble your customized dictionary like this for example https://ideone.com/CmAKGQ using re.finditer and the match object with the groups per iteration.

Comment: another challenge here, if there are duplicate items, say  BB  SOFTWARE3                                   1.2.3.4.6 and many such for other, in that case need to get highest value. currently it's picking lowest value.

Comment: since, we are using dict, dct = dict(re.findall(pattern, s, re.M)), definitely unique keys but somehow need to fetch the highest value when such duplicates are present.

Comment: @Learner That sounds like new question, but using ` re.findall(pattern, s, re.M)` will give you a list of tuples and perhaps you can order that list first before creating a dictionary.